# XML Deserialization with Windows Phone

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, compact-framework

When creating a type to serialize/de-serialize into xml, what do I use in place of System.SerializableAttribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to apply any specific attributes in order to serialize/deserialize a class, you just need to have public read/write properties for those things that need to be serialized.

If you're looking at persistence for tombstoning, then you should definitely take a look at Kevin Marshall's [WP7 Serialization blog post](http://blogs.claritycon.com/kevinmarshall/2010/11/03/wp7-serialization-comparison/). To skip to the summary, the best performance on WP7 is by using binary serialization.

Answer (score 0):

Just create public read/write properties.